# How to make a rectangle in Graphics in a transparent colour?

Tags: java, swing, colors, paintcomponent, translucency

I'm trying to paint a rectangle on my application in a red shade but I need to make it sort of transparent so that the component under it will still show.  However I still want that some colour will still show. The method where I'm drawing is the following:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (point != null) {
        int value = this.chooseColour(); // used to return how bright the red is needed

        if(value !=0){
            Color myColour = new Color(255, value,value );
            g.setColor(myColour);
            g.fillRect(point.x, point.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
        else{
            Color myColour = new Color(value, 0,0 );
            g.setColor(myColour);
            g.fillRect(point.x, point.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can make the red shade a bit transparent?  I don't need it completely transparent though.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
int alpha = 127; // 50% transparent
Color myColour = new Color(255, value, value, alpha);
```

See the [`Color` constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Color.html#constructor-summary) that take 4 arguments (of either `int` or `float`) for further details.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: (but it will works for Graphics2D objeccts not for Graphics)

```java
protected void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {
    if (point != null) {
        int value = this.chooseColour(); // used to return how bright the red is needed
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.8f));

        if(value !=0){
            Color myColour = new Color(255, value,value );
            g.setColor(myColour);
            g.fillRect(point.x, point.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
        else{
            Color myColour = new Color(value, 0,0 );
            g.setColor(myColour);
            g.fillRect(point.x, point.y, this.width, this.height);
        }

        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver); 
    }
}
```